# GeoServer faling to connect to web admin page or homepage

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to get started with learning GeoServer but can't get it to work.  I downloaded 2.6.1 for windows 7.  Install runs fine and my Java is updated.  When I tried to connect to either the web admin page or the homepage I get an "Application not Found" error.  I've tried setting it to different ports but same thing.
[image: GeoServerError]

Shot from GeoServer Starter command window
[image: GeoServer Starter]

Comment: did you start the service?

Comment: Yes, I run "Start GeoServer" but it still gives the same error.  I did get it running on my desktop.  Just can't figure out why it's not running on my laptop (both windows 7).

Comment: which installer did you use? are there any messages in the log? are you running as administrator>

Comment: I'm using the windows installer and selected "manual" during installation.  There are no messages under the log folder, but I posted the warnings from the GeoServer Starter command window above.  I tried running it as an administrator but got the same error.

Comment: Do you have a firewall running on your laptop? When iant says "logs" he means the stuff under 'C:\Program Files\GeoServer 2.6.1\logs'

Comment: I checked the logs file too and there were no errors.  Yes, I do have a firewall. I turned it off, started GeoServer, but got the same error when I tried to open the web admin page/homepage. I just downloaded PostGIS and any URL shortcut icon gives the same message.

Comment: Got it working.  Thanks for the help iant and BradHards!

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter the above message you need to set a default browser.  On Windows 7: Start--> Default Programs --> Set Your Default Programs --> Choose default browser --> Click Ok.

I did get a subsequent 404 error when I tried to connect to the web admin page, but I just tried a few different Ports other than the default 8080.